# On the inner workings of induction?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, induction

I always had some doubts on the inner workings of induction. So I decided to make a little experiment. I am familiar with the proof that the sum of the first $n$ integers is $\cfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$ so I decided to use it to make an experimentation. Using the technique given [here](http://qr.ae/RCeg8b) I've made the polynomial:

$$f(x)=-\frac{x^5}{120}+\frac{x^4}{8}-\frac{17 x^3}{24}+\frac{19 x^2}{8}-\frac{107 x}{60}+1$$

Which shares some of the first terms of $\cfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$, namely: $\{\underline 1, \underline 3, \underline 6,\underline{10},\underline{15},20,\dots\}$ from $\{1, 3, 6, 10, 15,21\dots\}$, instead of the sixth term be $21$, I altered it to $20$. Now I'm going to pretend that I think that the sum of the first $n$ integers is given by that polynomial and try to prove by induction. Following the same procedure I found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Example):

$$f(1)=1$$

$$f(k+1)=-\frac{(k+1)^5}{120} +\frac{(k+1)^4}{8} -\frac{17 (k+1)^3}{24} +\frac{19 (k+1)^2}{8} -\frac{107 (k+1)}{60}+1$$

But $$-\frac{(k+1)^5}{120} +\frac{(k+1)^4}{8} -\frac{17 (k+1)^3}{24} +\frac{19 (k+1)^2}{8} -\frac{107 (k+1)}{60}+1\\ \neq -\frac{k^5}{120} +\frac{(k)^4}{8} -\frac{17 (k)^3}{24} +\frac{19 (k)^2}{8} -\frac{107 (k)}{60}+1+(k+1).$$

Now according to the wikipedia article, I guess that the impossibility of writing it as $f(k+1)$ as $f(k)+(k+1)$ Is what makes this proof invalid. But what actually *forbids* me of writing $f(k+1)=f(k)+(k+1)$? Well, I'm doing induction on $\Bbb{N}$, I have sum and multiplication, then I guess that the axioms of the algebraic structure (semiring?) I'm working with, isn't it?

So, does this *proof* fails because It's impossible to write $f(k+1)=f(k)+(k+1)$ due to the semiring axioms and the [other proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Example) works because it's possible to write $f(k+1)=f(k)+(k+1)$ due to the semiring axioms?

This question is very important for me, In introductory books that have examples of proofs by induction that one is one of the most repeated. But those books usually seems to be omiting steps (in this case, the omitted step is the idea that those expressions can't be equal due to the semiring axioms.

Comment: Sorry, @whacka. We edited at the same time.

Comment: You could have made the example a lot simpler. For instance, $f(x)=2x-1$ would work (the odd numbers have the same first two terms as the triangular numbers).

Comment: @whacka Yes. I've also looked for some easy sequence (sharing some of the first terms) on OEIS. But as I read Farrugia's article I mentioned in the text, I had to use it because seemed fun.

Comment: The absence of a proof of $\forall k:f(k+1)=f(k)+(k+1)$ is an absence of an induction proof of $f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n k$. If you had actually claimed $\forall k:f(k+1)=f(k)+(k+1)$ then that claim would be false, and any proof that relies on a false claim is invalid. One can disprove the false claim by exhibiting a $k$ for which $f(k+1)\ne f(k)+(k+1)$. Dunno what you're on about with semiring axioms. Also, your last paragraph must be **wrong**: valid proofs by induction cannot rely on false induction steps.

Comment: If you use $21$, according to your link, you should get $\frac{x(x+1)}{2}$, as you are aware of. Your polynomial is only a interpolation on the numbers you gave. It is of course not identical to the function $\frac{x(x+1)}{2}$, so the statement $f(k+1)=f(k)+(k+1)$ is only true for $k=1,2,3,4$, since your first $5$ numbers follow the pattern.

Comment: @KittyL Yes. The *weird* thing is that using the first $5$ numbers of that sequence, it yields preciselly the formula of the sum of the first $n$ positive integers. I'm curious about why does it gives precisely $\cfrac{x(x+1)}{2}$ and not some other random formula. But I'll ask this on another ocasion.

Comment: Here is an intuitive explanation for $1+2+\cdots+n=n(n+1)/2$. Consider an $n\times(n+1)$ array of dots. Draw a line diagonally through it that separates it into an upper triangle and a lower triangle each with $1+2+\cdots+n$ dots. Also, it is not weird at all that one can interpolate any finite number of terms of a sequence with a likely-irrelevant polynomial function - this can be proved relatively easily.

Comment: Another way to think about it is three distinct points determine a parabola, just as two points determine a line. And in general, $n$ distinct points determine an $n-1$ degree polynomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have any chance of proving $\forall n:\sum_{i=1}^n i=f(n)$, then of course it must hold that
$$f(n+1)=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}i=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n i\right) +(n+1)=f(n)+(n+1)$$
For if this were not true, then the claim that $\forall n:\sum_{i=1}^n i=f(n)$ is false, and hence cannot be proven (assuming consistency and bla bla bla).

So yes, ultimately your proof will not work because indeed, generally $f(k+1)\not= f(k)+(k+1)$. This has nothing to do with induction though. No matter what proof strategy you use, it's just impossible to proof this claim, because it's false.

I'm not sure why you are thinking about semi-ring axioms. I feel like you're making this way to complicated. You are trying to proof a false claim, and thus no matter what strategy/method you try, nothing will work.

---

Edit: I think I see what you mean now. Yes ultimately it does come down to the axioms governing artimatric in the polynomial ring $R[k]$. By these axioms we have:
$$a=b\Leftrightarrow a-b=0$$
Since it forms a group under addition, and hence has the cancellation property. Then using the definition of $\dot{}$ and $+$ we find
$$-\frac{(k+1)^5}{120} +\frac{(k+1)^4}{8} -\frac{17 (k+1)^3}{24} +\frac{19 (k+1)^2}{8} -\frac{107 (k+1)}{60}+1\\-\left( -\frac{k^5}{120} +\frac{(k)^4}{8} -\frac{17 (k)^3}{24} +\frac{19 (k)^2}{8} -\frac{107 (k)}{60}+1+(k+1)\right)\\=-\frac{k^4}{24}+\frac{5k^3}{12}-\frac{35k^2}{24}+\frac{25k}{12}-1$$
And so by the definition of equality we see that
$$-\frac{k^4}{24}+\frac{5k^3}{12}-\frac{35k^2}{24}+\frac{25k}{12}-1\not= 0$$
And hence the claim is false.

So I think you are correct that on a certain level the falsehood (and consequently the failure of the proof) is due to the axioms of the arithmetic in $R[k]$.

---

Edit2: I was confused; you're not working in a polynomial ring here at all. You're just working in the ring $\mathbb{Q}$. As a matter of fact the expression wouldn't even be well defined in a polynomial ring: having $k$, the indeterminate, over the $\sum$ sign makes no sense. Since I don't feel like rewriting the thing I'll just leave it here, I'm sure you can correct it yourself.

Comment: No, I'm not trying to prove it's right. I'm trying to understand what are the laws that forbid me of writing $f(k+1)= f(k)+(k+1)$. And I guess it has something to do with the semiring axioms.

Comment: @Voyska see my edit

Comment: Good, that's the spirit. When I read about induction, everything seemed to be connected and it made no sense. After some thought, I realized that induction is one thing that can be used to prove ideas in another ideologically feasible frameworks, such as graphs, semirings (in this case), etc.

Answer (score 1):

The axiom you are over-looking is not any of the semi-ring axioms (induction does not hold in any arbitrary semi-ring) but *this* axiom of the natural numbers:

If $S \subseteq \Bbb N$ and:

$a)\ 0 \in S\\b)\ x \in S \implies x+1 \in S$

(some texts write $s(n)$ or $x'$ instead of $x+1$, especially if addition has not yet been defined).

then $S = \Bbb N$.

This is (one of the forms of) the Principle of Mathematical Induction. There is no hope of *proving* this, it is taken as an intrinsic property we wish natural numbers to have: we can enumerate them (completely) by "counting".

An induction proof works by taking:

$S = \{k \in \Bbb N: P(k)\}$, for some propositional statement $P$ with subject $k$, and then proving $S = \Bbb N$ using PMI.

I urge you to try to prove $n < 6$ by induction, and see what goes wrong (this is not so different than your original approach).

Comment: Why doesn't induction works on semirings? After all, we're dealing with $\Bbb{N}$, addition and multiplication. And it follows [these axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring#Definition).

Comment: I mean, to write $f(k+1)$ as $f(k)+(k+1)$, I need to have the idea of equivalent rewriting, and I guess this idea comes from the semiring axioms.